# Random crash on setting UITabBarButton label attributed text (Tab Title)

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am not able to reproduce this crash but received this kind of crashes multiple times from production build. In my app tab bar is loaded from storyboard only and tab bar is always hidden all the time.

Does it's main cause is low memory? Any guess, how to solve or reproduce this kind of problems

```
Hardware Model:      iPad2,4
OS Version:      iPhone OS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x393f71fc
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2e766f4b __exceptionPreprocess + 131
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x38e386af objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2e766e8d +[NSException raise:format:] + 104
3   Foundation                          0x2f089aff -[NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:] + 122
4   Foundation                          0x2f088efb -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:attributes:] + 310
5   UIKit                               0x30ee8ed7 -[NSAttributedString(UILabelAdditions) _ui_synthesizeAttributedSubstringFromRange:usingDefaultAttributes:] + 86
6   UIKit                               0x30ee8c9f -[UILabel _synthesizedAttributedText] + 1010
7   UIKit                               0x30ee8307 -[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 222
8   UIKit                               0x30ee8213 -[UILabel textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:] + 54
9   UIKit                               0x30ee80fb -[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 162
10  UIKit                               0x30ee8049 -[UILabel sizeThatFits:] + 32
11  UIKit                               0x30ee7f37 -[UIView(Geometry) sizeToFit] + 126
12  UIKit                               0x31002be1 -[UITabBarButton initWithImage:selectedImage:label:withInsets:] + 388
13  UIKit                               0x31001a1f -[UITabBarItem(Static) _createViewForTabBar:showingBadge:withTint:idiom:] + 1170
14  UIKit                               0x31001583 -[UITabBarItem(Static) _createViewForTabBar:showingBadge:idiom:] + 38
15  UIKit                               0x30ffd859 -[UITabBarItem(Static) _updateViewForIdiom:positionItems:] + 160
16  UIKit                               0x31004c43 -[UITabBar(Static) _configureItems:] + 406
17  UIKit                               0x310042db -[UITabBar(Static) _positionTabBarButtons:ignoringItem:] + 1234
18  UIKit                               0x3100133f -[UITabBar setItems:animated:] + 1358
19  UIKit                               0x31000d29 -[UITabBarController _rebuildTabBarItemsAnimated:] + 800
20  UIKit                               0x310051f9 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 76
21  UIKit                               0x30eeb6e5 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 72
22  UIKit                               0x31008bf7 -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 218
23  UIKit                               0x31008077 -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 134
24  UIKit                               0x30ef40eb -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 346
25  CoreFoundation                      0x2e6aff65 __53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 52
26  CoreFoundation                      0x2e6a994d -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 220
27  UIKit                               0x30ef4265 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 724
28  UIKit                               0x3106a4bf -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 846
29  UIKit                               0x30f88273 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 418
30  UIKit                               0x30f8807d -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 44
31  UIKit                               0x30f88015 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 184
32  UIKit                               0x30ed9da3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 346
33  QuartzCore                          0x30b60c6b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 142
34  QuartzCore                          0x30b5c47b CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 350
35  QuartzCore                          0x30b5c30d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
36  QuartzCore                          0x30b5bd1f CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 230
37  QuartzCore                          0x30b5bb2f CA::Transaction::commit() + 314
38  QuartzCore                          0x30b5585d CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
39  CoreFoundation                      0x2e7321cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
40  CoreFoundation                      0x2e72fb71 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 284
41  CoreFoundation                      0x2e72feb3 __CFRunLoopRun + 730
42  CoreFoundation                      0x2e69ac27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
43  CoreFoundation                      0x2e69aa0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
44  GraphicsServices                    0x3336e283 GSEventRunModal + 138
45  UIKit                               0x30f3e049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
46  MyApp                               main (in MyApp) (main.m:16)
47  libdyld.dylib                       0x39340ab7 start + 2


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x393f71fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x393a7ffd abort + 77
2   MyApp                               uncaught_exception_handler (in MyApp) + 27
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2e76724f __handleUncaughtException + 579
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x38e3890f _objc_terminate() + 175
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x386ed1c7 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 79
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x386ecd2d __cxa_increment_exception_refcount + 1
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x38e387f7 objc_exception_rethrow + 43
8   CoreFoundation                      0x2e69ac9d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 641
9   CoreFoundation                      0x2e69aa0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
10  GraphicsServices                    0x3336e283 GSEventRunModal + 138
11  UIKit                               0x30f3e049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
12  MyApp                               main (in MyApp) (main.m:16)
```

Comment: Are you using this method anywhere in your app: replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:?

Comment: No, all is loaded from storyboard and I guess the text is going to set to UILabel is a UITabBarItem title.

Comment: Did you have a chance to resolve this?

Comment: I have done lot of memory optimisation to fix such a crashes, after that I didn't saw such a crash on my app. This is because of increasing memory pressure while loading tab bar (containing heavy view/viewcontrollers)

Answer (score 0):

From you crash log, line 5

```
    5   UIKit                               0x30ee8ed7 -[NSAttributedString(UILabelAdditions) _ui_synthesizeAttributedSubstringFromRange:usingDefaultAttributes:] + 86
```

seems like you generate your attribute string based on

```
     - (NSAttributedString *)attributedSubstringFromRange:(NSRange)aRange
```

Maybe set a break point at that code, and check if your string length is larger than or equal to the range.

Comment: It's a default title that get added from storyboard to UITabBarItem label.

Comment: @atrane i don't know if you could provide some code snippets, that would be much easier for us to help you...